# "got any eggs" vs. "got any egg"

Tags: meaning, singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, food

> Have we got any egg**s**?

vs

> Have we got any egg?

What is the difference between these two sentences in terms of meaning?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"Eggs" is countable and means those oval things that are laid by birds.

"Egg" isn't countable. It normally wouldn't make sense to say "egg" as eggs themselves are countable, but you could say "have we got any egg" if you were in a restaurant kitchen that used powdered or liquid egg rather than individual shelled eggs.

Comment: You might also use "egg" if you're talking about a bit of cooked egg - "Have I got any egg on my face?"

Comment: Politicians sometimes have egg on their face, but occasionally they have eggs on their coats.

Comment: Eggs can also be laid by reptiles, and echindas.  Which is gross.

Comment: ""egg" isn't countable" - it might not *always* be uncountable, but it can be countable if you say "an egg", "one egg" or "give me any (i.e. one) egg".

Comment: You could also use "egg" in some cases where they were made from fresh, but subsequently mixed together.

Comment: Ever spilled a pan full of scramble? Egg goes everywhere.

Comment: Interesting that we still use the "eggs" countable form for types of eggs that are pretty much uncountable: frogs, fish, etc.

Comment: @SteveBennett They're *conceptually* countable, and a suitably dedicated person has already counted eggs per animal in the lab. It's just not practical in most cases, but they are still individual items.

Comment: Yeah, but rice grains are conceptually countable too, even though we just say "rice".

Comment: That's because you have *rice* (uncountable) and *grains of rice* (not 6 million rices) and *frogspawn* (uncountable) and *eggs* (countable). In the case of avian and reptilian eggs there isn't an uncountable noun - there is a clutch of eggs, but clutches are countable too.